# getview of Baseapdapter always returns 0 index in android

Tags: android, adapter, baseadapter

I have a problem that getView method of my Adapter always returns 0 as a index. Therefore only one image is showing 2 times in my GridView. So, please suggest any solution regarding the same.

**Code: Adapter**

```
public class LibraryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context _context;
    ArrayList<String> listMags;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap;

    public LibraryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> listMags, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap)
    {
        _context = context;
        this.listMags = listMags;
        this.hashMap = hashMap;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return listMags.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return listMags.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2)
    {
        ItemHolder itemHolder;
        String magName = listMags.get(arg0);
        if (arg1 == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflaterObj = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            itemHolder = new ItemHolder();
            arg1 = layoutInflaterObj.inflate(R.layout.library_grid_item, null);

            itemHolder.imgMag = (ImageView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.imgIssuesGridItem);

            itemHolder.tvMagName = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.tvIssuesDate);
            arg1.setTag(itemHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            itemHolder = (ItemHolder) arg1.getTag();
        }
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MAGZ/"+magName+"/"+hashMap.get(magName).get(0)+"/"+(hashMap.get(magName).get(0).replace(magName, ""))+arg0+".png");
        //itemHolder.imgIssueItem.setImageUrl(getItem(position).getImage_path(), imageLoader);
        itemHolder.imgMag.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        itemHolder.tvMagName.setText((new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MAGZ/"+magName+"/"+hashMap.get(magName).get(0))).getName());

        return arg1;
    }

    static class ItemHolder
    {
        ImageView imgMag;
        TextView tvMagName;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post here your xml defining your gridview.

Comment: @Sanat Pandey Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override getItemId() method like this:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0)
{
    return arg0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your below lines besides showing position `0` add the `arg0` instead as below:

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MAGZ/"+magName+"/"+hashMap.get(magName).get(arg0)+"/"+(hashMap.get(magName).get(arg0).replace(magName, ""))+arg0+".png");

 itemHolder.imgMag.setImageBitmap(bmp);
 itemHolder.tvMagName.setText((new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/MAGZ/"+magName+"/"+hashMap.get(magName).get(arg0))).getName());
```

And also change your `getItemId` method as below:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0)
{
    return arg0;
}
```

Comment: I changed the code according to your comment but it remains same. Always returns 0 in getView.

Comment: Is your GridView Height is wrap_content in xml file?

Comment: Thanks Piyush its solved, but I am very keen to know that the reason behind this, can you give me the exact reason behind this.

Answer (score 0):

you have given return 0

try this

```
   @Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}
```